# AngularJS doesnt show json data

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been trying out AngularJS by creating a simple gallery that gets images from a json file, but somehow I can't seem to display the data.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="portfolioApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="GalleryController" >
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="image in gallery.galleryData">
                <a ng-href="">{{image.IMAGE_WIDTH}}
                    <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{IMAGE_LOCATION+image.image}}" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('portfolioApp',[]);
app.controller('GalleryController',['$http', function($http){
  var gallery = this;
  gallery = [];

  gallery.IMAGE_WIDTH = 405;
  gallery.IMAGE_LOCATION = "http://rabidgadfly.com/assets/angular/gallery1/";

  $http.get("images.json").success(function(data){
  gallery.galleryData = data;  
});
}]);
```

I think the issue has something to do with the scope of the gallery variable, but i'm not sure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBGku.png

Comment: could you please tell me, what `images.json` contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Scopes provide APIs ($apply) to propagate any model changes through
>   the system into the view from outside of the "Angular realm"
>   (controllers, services, Angular event handlers).

So you should add gallery to `$scope` then it can be accessed in the View:

```
var app = angular.module('portfolioApp',[]);
app.controller('GalleryController',['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
  $scope.gallery = [];

  $scope.gallery.IMAGE_WIDTH = 405;
  $scope.gallery.IMAGE_LOCATION = "http://rabidgadfly.com/assets/angular/gallery1/";

  $http.get("images.json").success(function(data){
    $scope.gallery.galleryData = data;  
  });
}]);
```